# Notepad++ Regex cut last word of line and paste it to start

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have huge list in Notepad++. I want to cut last word for each line and paste it to start of each line.

**For e.g.**

```
@calories decimal,
@carbs decimal,
```

I looking for result like below

```
decimal @calories,
decimal @carbs,
```

I didn't found any similar type question. Anyone knows, how to do that?

Comment: Do the lines only ever contain two words like that?

Comment: Also, have you made any attempt at all yourself yet?

Comment: I found this but not worked. https://superuser.com/questions/810188/notepad-copy-word-from-start-of-line-to-end-of-line

Comment: yes, only two words.

Comment: Take a look at this example. Very close https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072599/notepad-can-you-use-regex-to-move-the-last-word-on-a-line-to-the-front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture both words in capturing groups and switch their positions. Search for

```
^@(\w+) (\w+),$
```

and replace with

```
\2 @\1,
```

Comment: That's awesome. It worked :) Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Why not capture `(@\w+)`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
Find What: `^@(\w+) (\w+),$`
Replace With: `\2 @\1,`